# Create a map of objects without destroingthe objects

Tags: c++, class, object, dictionary

I am trying to create a map which contains the objects with different arguments.

But I found that after inserting the pair, the object will be destroyed.

If I try to use the function in this object.For example:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Test{
    public:
        Test(double value) : value_(value){}
        ~Test(){std::cout<< "destroyed";}
        void plusone()  {value_ += 1;}
    private:
        double value_;
};

int main(){
    std::map<long, Test> map;

    map.insert(std::make_pair(1, Test(1.2)));
    map[1].plusone();
    return 0;
}
```

It will show:
[Error] no matching function for call to 'Class::Class()'

[Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

How can I do this?

Comment: In your case, it seems that you may use `map::at` (throw if not found) instead of `map::operator[]` (try to insert default object, and return inserted/found object).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `map[1]` can only be used when the mapped type has a default constructor. This is because if the key is not found then a default-constructed object is inserted, but the compiler has to generate code for this at compile-time.

If you do not want to add a default constructor then you have to use different lookup code, e.g.:

```
auto it = map.find(1);
if ( it != map.end() )
    it->second.memberfuncion();
```

Also, your error message has nothing to do with destroying objects, as your title mentions.

---

In the code `map.insert(std::make_pair(1, Class(argument)));`, you create a temporary object `Class(argument)`, and copy that into the map. Then the temporary object is destroyed.

If you want to avoid this and construct directly in the map, use `map.emplace(1, argument);`.

Comment: Note that `emplace()` is only available in C++11 and later.

Comment: thank you so much ,very detail explanation.
btw which one you prefer ?
syntax [ ] or .find

Comment: yes, in C++03 there is no option but to copy the object in

Comment: @CHOCOLEO well I prefer `[]` personally but as I explain in my answer, for some `Class`es it is not possible

Comment: @M.M Would you like to give one example? as I though there is no harm adding a default constructor to the class. Thanks

Comment: @CHOCOLEO my answer includes an example of `find`, and your question includes an example of `[]`  (if you added a default constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Item access via `map.operator[]` [requires your mapped type to be default constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

If it is not default constructible, use [`map.find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) which has no such requirement.